# Random Cut Forest model evaluation strategies (Confusion matrix,Accuracy and precision_recall_fscore

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS sagemker random cut forest algorithm to detect the anomalies.

```
import boto3
import sagemaker

containers = {
    'us-west-2': '174872318107.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/randomcutforest:latest',
    'us-east-1': '382416733822.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/randomcutforest:latest',
    'us-east-2': '404615174143.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/randomcutforest:latest',
    'eu-west-1': '438346466558.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/randomcutforest:latest',
    'ap-southeast-1':'475088953585.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/randomcutforest:latest'
    }
region_name = boto3.Session().region_name
container = containers[region_name]

session = sagemaker.Session()

rcf = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container,
    sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge',
    sagemaker_session=session)

rcf.set_hyperparameters(
    num_samples_per_tree=200,
    num_trees=250,
    feature_dim=1,
    eval_metrics =["accuracy", "precision_recall_fscore"])

s3_train_input = sagemaker.session.s3_input(
    s3_train_data,
    distribution='ShardedByS3Key',
    content_type='application/x-recordio-protobuf')

rcf.fit({'train': s3_train_input})
```

( referred from --> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-built-in-amazon-sagemaker-random-cut-forest-algorithm-for-anomaly-detection/)

used above code to train the model, didn't find the way to evaluate model.
how to get the Accuracy and F score after deploying the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get evaluation metrics you need to provide an extra channel called "test" during training. The test channel must contained labeled data. It is explained in the official documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/randomcutforest.html :

> Amazon SageMaker Random Cut Forest supports the train and test data channels. The optional test channel is used to compute accuracy, precision, recall, and F1-score metrics on labeled data. Train and test data content types can be either application/x-recordio-protobuf or text/csv formats. For the test data, when using text/csv format, the content must be specified as text/csv;label_size=1 where the first column of each row represents the anomaly label: "1" for an anomalous data point and "0" for a normal data point. You can use either File mode or Pipe mode to train RCF models on data that is formatted as recordIO-wrapped-protobuf or as CSV
>
> Also note ... the test channel only supports S3DataDistributionType=FullyReplicated

Thanks,

Julio